# Find probability of 3 heads, given there is at least one head

Tags: probability

The question stated:

> Find the probability that, in three tosses of a fair coin, there are three heads, given that there is at least one head.

And provided an answer of:

> $\displaystyle\frac {\Pr (HHH)}{1-\Pr (TTT)}=\displaystyle\frac {\displaystyle\frac {1}{8}}{\displaystyle\frac {7}{8}}=\displaystyle\frac {1}{7}$

Which I'm having trouble understanding.

---

I understand that $\Pr (HHH) = \frac{1}{8}$ and $\Pr (TTT) = \frac{1}{8}$, but I don't see why they divided the top by the complementary?

Could someone please explain this in words?

<sup>Please understand that I'm working at an year 12 level, and probably won't understand higher level math jargon.</sup>

Comment: Are you asking for the formula for conditional expectation?  Or the reasoning behind the formula?

Comment: @MichaelBurr The reasoning

Comment: Do you understand conditional probability, in general? Are you taking a course in probability?

Comment: @JohnDouma I'm still learning conditional probability, so not really. The course is not specifically probability, but contains it as an area of study

Comment: If you learn conditional probability then you will find that this problem is really a simple exercise. Take a look at [this site](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability-events-conditional.html) and see if you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample space of three tosses with atleast one head is = {HHH,HHT,HTH,THH,HTT,THT,TTH}=7

Probability of three Head is = $\frac{1}{7}$